# Detached exception na tabela associativa

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou encontrando o seguinte problema na hora de fazer um certo cadastro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.arena.model.Pessoa
>         at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
>         at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
>         at br.com.arena.dao.PessoaTimeDAO.cadastrar(PessoaTimeDAO.java:18)
>         at br.com.arena.util.Persistir.main(Persistir.java:54)
>     Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.arena.model.Pessoa
>         at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
>         at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:636)
>         at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:628)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:28)
>         ... 18 more
> ```

Meu objetivo é realizar o cadastro de um Time, esse time fica associado a uma Pessoa através de uma tabela associativa Pessoa_Time

Pessoa Model:

```java
@Entity
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id_Pessoa")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nomeUsuario;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String senhaUsuario;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nomeCompleto;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer idade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime; 

    public Pessoa (){}

    public Pessoa (Pessoa pessoa){
        this.id = pessoa.getId();
        this.nomeUsuario = pessoa.getNomeUsuario();
        this.senhaUsuario = pessoa.getSenhaUsuario();
        this.nomeCompleto = pessoa.getNomeCompleto();
        this.email = pessoa.getEmail();
        this.idade = pessoa.getIdade();
    }
```

Time Model:

```java
@Entity
public class Time implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id_Time")
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String senhaTime;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "time",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="time",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CampeonatoTime> listaCampeonatoTime;

    public Time(){}

    public Time(Time time){
        this.id = time.getId();
        this.nome = time.getNome();
        this.senhaTime = time.getSenhaTime();
    }
```

PessoaTime Model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_time")
public class PessoaTime implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="id_PessoaTime")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_time")
    private Time time;

    private Cargo cargo;

    public PessoaTime (){}

    public PessoaTime (PessoaTime pessoaTime){
        this.id = pessoaTime.getId();
        this.pessoa = pessoaTime.getPessoa();
        this.time = pessoaTime.getTime();
        this.cargo = pessoaTime.getCargo();
    }
```

PessoaDAO:

```java
    public void cadastrar(Pessoa pessoa){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(pessoa);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

TimeDAO:

```java
    public void cadastrar(Time time){
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(time);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

PessoaTimeDAO:

```java
    public void cadastrar(PessoaTime pessoaTime){
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
        getEntityManager().persist(pessoaTime);
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Persistir.java: Classe Main

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Time time = new Time();
        TimeDAO timedao = new TimeDAO();
        PessoaTime pessoatime = new PessoaTime();
        PessoaTimeDAO pessoatimedao = new PessoaTimeDAO();

        time.setNome("Time novo");
        time.setSenhaTime("4");

        timedao.cadastrar(time);        

        PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();

        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.setNomeUsuario("pessoa 2");
        pessoa.setSenhaUsuario("1234567892");
        pessoa.setNomeCompleto("pessoa people 2");
        pessoa.setEmail("people22112@gmail.com");
        pessoa.setIdade(22);

        pessoaDAO.cadastrar(pessoa);

        pessoatime.setPessoa(pessoa);
        pessoatime.setTime(time);
        pessoatime.setCargo(Cargo.ADMINISTRADOR);

        pessoatimedao.cadastrar(pessoatime);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido!

O erro estava no CascadeType dos atributos:

Pessoa:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime;
```

Time:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "time",cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private List<PessoaTime> listaPessoaTime;
```

PessoaTime:

```
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_time")
    private Time time;
```